# My function says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).reverse is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#upBtn").click(function () {
            $("input:checked").each(function () {
                moveUp(this);
            })
        })
        $("#downBtn").click(function () {
            $("input:checked").reverse().each(function () {
                moveDown(this);
            })
        })
    });

    function moveUp(v) {
        let temp = $(v).parent().parent();
        temp.prev().before(temp);
    }

    function moveDown(v) {
        let temp = $(v).parent().parent();
        temp.next().after(temp);
    }
</script>
```

The `moveUp` Methode works fine.

But when I use `moveDown`, Chrome console says

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).reverse is not a function.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: jQuery has no `reverse` function like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a `reverse()` that operates on a jQuery object.

Perhaps you meant `$('input:checked').get().reverse()`, which translates the object into a base array and then reverses it. Of course, in order to call `each()` (a jQuery method) on it, you'd have to convert it back to a jQuery object:

```
$( $('input:checked').get().reverse() ).each(function(){…})
```

Though, another option would be not to use `each()` and use vanilla JavaScript:

```
$('input:checked').get().reverse().forEach(elem=>{
  moveDown(elem)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice has been a great help to me.